# Running time in FPT

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

For a certain parameter $k$, is the algorithm with the running time of $O(k.n^{\log{n}})$ in class $FPT$? I would appreciate if you can kindly guide me through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a running time like $f(k)n^{g(n,k)}$ is not suitable for any non-constant function $g$.

$\mathrm{FPT}$ is the class of problems computable in time $O(f(k)\cdot n^{c})$ for some *fixed* $c \in \mathbb{N}$. The "fixed" is very important, much the same as $\mathrm{P}$ is the class of problems computable in time $O(n^{c})$ for some fixed $c$ - you don't get to even have a small non-constant function (such as $n^{\log n}$) in the exponent and still be in $\mathrm{P}$.